# DC solar voltage regulation

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator

I am attempting to use a CTEC D250se in a 12v dc vehicle setting.  It is a dual batt/batt solar charge controller.  The max solar input voltage is 23v and I realized i have a 36v solar panel.  The rep said it wont work and has offered no solutions.  My question is how do I regulate the solar input?
I have looked at a few Buck style trans but they say not for use w solar power.  Its a really good product and I would appreciate any solutions.  Space is an issue.

Comment: can't you give all the specs and tolerances of every part, solarity and load? Otherwise, no chance. This is a complex matter of matching impedances while regulating voltage with pulsed current.

Comment: Forgot to say max amperage is 30A.  New territory for me.  I usually deal with AC installations.

Comment: DC solar controllers are not expensive! Finding one rated for >36V will probably be the cheapest solution.

Comment: I will look for the links.

Comment: I have a controller 0-100v rated but it is not a dual charge or batt/batt charger.  the idea is use the vehicle alternator as a charge source as well.  this component sw's charging automatically

Comment: https://smartercharger.com/products/ctek-d250se

Comment: I also asked if i could use the Solar charge controller in tandem with the d250se and the rep said no, it wont work.  Im sure there is a solution other than buying a new panel.  This panel is top notch but i may be wrong.  Im just looking for some expert advice.

Comment: The panel is 36V 300W

Comment: The original controller is a BlueSolar MPPT 100-30.  IDK if this helps but thnx for your time everyone.